# add docx file as configMap in kubernetess

Tags: kubernetes-helm, docx

Hi I am trying to mount small docx file to pod,  here is my helm-template configmap:

```
{- range .Values.resourcesFrom.file}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: file-{{ . | lower | replace "_" "-" }}
  labels:
  {{- include "labels.global" $ | indent 4 }}
data:
  {{ . }} : |-
{{- $.Files.Get (printf "resources/files/%s" .) | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

but output configMap contains TEST_FILE.docx: null

Do you have any idea how to do this?
I'd like to mention that this file will be less that 1MB so to configMap limit should not be exceeded.

I tried to mount small docx file as volume to pod
output config map contains TEST_FILE.docx: null

Comment: Does it work with a simple txt file?

Comment: no it does not work